# Is Doctor Doom actually a doctor?

Tags: marvel, dr-doom

When Victor Von Doom was attending college at Empire State University, he accidentally created an explosion and was expelled.

Was he already a doctor at that point, did he become a doctor at a different school later on, or is he not actually a doctor?

Comment: He has a PhD in Horribleness

Comment: “Please, ‘Doctor’ Doom is my father. Call me Jeremy.”

Comment: No, but he did stay at a Universal Inn Express last night

Comment: I didn't spend eight years at Doom medical school to have people call me "Mr Doom".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to his (new) origin story in [Books of Doom #04](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/books-of-doom/4050-21927/), we finally learn that the title was *self-appointed*.

[image]

---

This ties in very nicely with his original origin story (from the 1964 [Fantastic Four Annual #02](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Annual_Vol_1_2)). Doom basically considers himself to have learned everything that the University can teach, and hence *equal to a PhD*, even if they've not *formally* bestowed the title on him.

[image]

Comment: I love how Doom was able to sneak a giant machine into his dorm when most students get busted for having a cat.

Comment: @rogueJedi - I got into troube for having my own minifridge, let alone a device capable of transferring my soul-essence to the Astral Plane.

Comment: Incidentally, if you've learnt everything they can teach then you get a masters. If you want a PhD you have to learn something new.

Comment: Yes, he became eccentric *after* he permanently grafted a metal mask to his face and had you build a giant wall of screens.